# VBA to adjust row heights that have value to some total length

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of rows that contain the value of "1" in column L. I want vba to adjust the height of each of these rows to a total height of 375 (or 500 pixels). Any ideas? A macro is run prior to this so that all the other rows not containing "1" are deleted out and they are grouped together. The range changes anywhere from row 8 to row 30.

Comment: Your question will be much better received if you show some effort other than "Please write this code for me."

Comment: *Which exact part* of this is giving you problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
Sub changeRowHeight()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim firstCell As Range
    Set firstCell = Range("L2")

    If IsEmpty(firstCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) Then
       Set myRange = firstCell
    Else
       Set myRange = firstCell.Parent.Range(firstCell, firstCell.End(xlDown))
    End If

    'MsgBox (myRange.Address)

    myRange.RowHeight = 375 / myRange.Count
End Sub
```

---

Started with this:

[image]

Results:

[image]